# How to Update UserControl (Chart) in MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, charts

I have a chart embedded in a usercontrol

> PlotControl.xaml (PlotControl.xaml.cs)

This plot control is used on a View in MVVM.

NOW! when I update the UI of PlotControl (e.g. I draw vertical and horizontal markers on chart), these updates are not visible on View (unless I do double click on the View or do a Minimize-Maximize window).

**Is there a way the updated UI is updated automatically on View?**

View code looks like:

```
<Grid Margin="4">
   <nms:PlotControl  x:Name="PlotControl" Margin="10,10" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
</nms:PlotControl>
```

Snippet from PlotControl.xaml.cs code looks like:

```
ChartPanel cpnl = new ChartPanel();
chart.View.Layers.Add(cpnl);

ChartMarker rightVerticalMarker = new ChartMarker(chart, MarketType.RightVertical);
rightVerticalMarker.DataPoint = new Point(30, double.NaN);

cpnl.Children.Add(rightVerticalMarker);
cpnl.UpdateLayout();
chart.UpdateLayout();
```

ChartMarker is simply a line Horizontal (or Vertical) defined by enum MarketType.

NOTE: I have been searching for this problem since two days in SO, but nowhere could I find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updates can be forced by Arrange methods. Here is what I have found, which solved my problem.

```
Size userControlSize = this.RenderSize; //original size of userControl
Size chartSize = chart.RenderSize;    // original size of chart
chart.Arrange(chart.View.PlotRect); // forcing layout elements on chart
chart.Arrange(new Rect(chartSize)); // setting the chart size to original value
Arrange(new Rect(userControlSize)); // setting the userControl size to original value
```